# Has anyone used Brython with Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, brython

I'm a fan of moving fast. I love WordPress (and available themes) and Python because I can develop concepts and prototype quickly.  I'm not a fan of jscript....

I'm wondering if anyone has tried to use Brython with WordPress to create some interesting client-side capabilities.

- What are your thoughts?
- How would you even approach this?
- If you have, what challenges have you run into?

Thanks!

Comment: Woah this is a cool idea. I have nothing to contribute, but I am bookmarking hoping someone responds or you update with your own journey